# CFGFWK-64038 : A target must be associated with app-svc-name "xxx"

Tags: obiee, oracle-data-integrator

I'm triying to install Oracle products . I installed OBIIE and now I'm trying to install ODI on the same domain but I have this error :

**java.lang.Exception: CFGFWK-64038 : A target must be associated with app-svc-name "oraclediagent". 
CFGFWK-64038: Specify a valid target.**

Any Idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, this error will be triggered when you create a JavaEE agent it will be asking what is the app SVC name need to be used.

we will be creating a managed server at a point, there in the right side will be asking the server group where we need to select the proper group name, usually we will be selecting "JRF-MAN-SVR" for javaEE agent.

let me know if this resolves your issue.